# launching cassandra cqlsh python not found

Tags: python-2.7, cqlsh, cassandra-2.2

I am trying to install cassandra version 2.2.0 and I found the compatible python version for it is 2.7.10 then I installed it. 
when I type in terminal

python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.10

but when I launch cassandra server and want to start cassandra query language shell by typing 
root@eman:/usr/local/cassandra# bin/cqlsh
bin/cqlsh: 19: bin/cqlsh: python: not found

how could I fix this issue

thanks in advance

Comment: what does `which python` say?

Comment: it says nothing

Comment: but when I type whereis python it appears  python: /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 /etc/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/share/python

Comment: when I Type:
 ls -l /usr/bin/python*
it appears to me:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 23 19:20 /usr/bin/python3 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     976 Nov 27  2015 /usr/bin/python3-jsondiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3662 Nov 27  2015 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpatch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1342 Oct 24  2015 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpointer
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4460336 Nov 17 19:23 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4460336 Nov 17 19:23 /usr/bin/python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m

Answer (score 1):

For centos 8 and other similarly:

- Install python 2.7
- Then, prior to invoking cqlsh, run:

  sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `python` is not installed on your machine (for whatever reason).

`cqlsh` shells out to `python` (in a rather strange way): https://github.com/spiside/cqlsh/blob/6f5b680fed2e48e37107fd1da272e351e5ac257d/cqlsh#L1-L30

Unrelated to this stackoverflow issue, I attempted to fix (and probably fixed) this in the latest version of cqlsh: https://github.com/spiside/cqlsh/commit/a880445ec9d05cfa552928d5a88d1457640456b6

If you can upgrade `cqlsh` it *may* fix this.

If you can't upgrade `cqlsh` any of the following things should fix this:
- If you're on an `debian`-like system `apt-get install python-minimal` -- this provides the `/usr/bin/python` file that seems to be missing (for whatever reason)
- If your package manager has a package which provides the `/usr/bin/python` symlink, install that
- Otherwise, set up a symlink that's on your path, for example `ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python`